# Why is the vanilla JS example for RxDB not working

Tags: javascript, nosql, pouchdb, rxdb

I've followed the instructions at [GitHub](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/tree/master/examples/vanilla), but the example doesn't work.
The app shows "Starting database".
At the browser console there is this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: storage is undefined
  _callee6$                                       http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:11032
  tryCatch                                        http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:70936
  invoke                                          http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:71167
  defineIteratorMethods                           http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:70992
  asyncGeneratorStep                              http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14068
  _next                                           http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14090
  _asyncToGenerator                               http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14097
  _asyncToGenerator                               http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14086
  _createRxDatabaseStorageInstances               http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:11060
  createRxDatabaseStorageInstances                http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:11017
  _callee7$                                       http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:11075
  tryCatch                                        http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:70936
  invoke                                          http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:71167
  defineIteratorMethods                           http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:70992
asyncGeneratorStep                                http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14068
  _next                                           http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14090
  _asyncToGenerator                               http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14097
  _asyncToGenerator                               http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:14086
  _prepare                                        http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:11104
  prepare                                         http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:11064
  createRxDatabase                                http://127.0.0.1:20202/dist/rxdb.browserify.js:11142
  <anonymous>                                     http://127.0.0.1:20202/main.js:33
```

When I try to add a hero and click the "Insert" button this error appears at the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: col is not defined
  addHero http://127.0.0.1:20202/main.js:97
  onclick http://127.0.0.1:20202/:1
```

Ist this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [rxdb v10 release notes](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/blob/master/orga/releases/10.0.0.md#you-can-help):

> "...many (*example projects*) are outdated and need updates."

I was as well not able to get it working.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer